# Mail Server Solution IMAP/POP3

Tags: windows, outlook, imap, pop3, mail-server

we have our emails in hostmosnter under our domain. we want to use outlook on our machines at work, so imap was a solution to keep them synzronized, but the problem is we use diffrent machines and we want a mail server to store those emails rather than fetching them every time from hostmonster.com

what kind of software that can fetch those emails from the server and save them and internally we rely on our mail server for this purpose. Note that MS exchange server doesnt support IMAP or POP3 mail fetching

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exchange doesnt have POP3 support. The only solution was to use a third party addon: http://www.servolutions.com/popcon.htm